# limit of $x^2 \frac{\sin\frac{1}{x}}{\sin x}=0$ as $x\rightarrow 0$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Im having trouble trying to show that  $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2\sin\frac{1}{x}}{\sin x}=0$. I tried l'hospitals rule since $\lim_{x \to 0} x^2 \sin(\frac{1}{x})=0$ and $\lim_{x \to 0} \sin x=0$. But when I work it out it doesn't work. I think im supposed to use the squeeze theorem. I know that $-1\leq \sin x\leq x$. But from here im stuck.

Answer (score 4):

**Hints:**

i)

> $$\lim x^2 \frac{\sin(1/x)}{\sin(x)} = \lim\frac{x}{\sin(x)}\cdot\lim x\sin(1/x). $$

ii)

> $$ |x\sin(1/x)|\leq |x|. $$

Comment: oh i see thanks. I can use l'hospital's rule for lim$\frac{x}{sin x}$.

Comment: @user60887: Yes, and for the other one, you can use the squeeze theorem.

Comment: @Michael Hardy: Thanks for the editing.

Comment: @user60887: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can factor the  limit into two pieces and handle them as f ollows.
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x}{\sin(x)}\cdot x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = 1\cdot 0 = 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\eqalign{
  & \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} {x^2}\sin \left( {{1 \over x}} \right).{1 \over {\sin x}} = L  \cr 
  & L = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \left[ {x.\sin \left( {{1 \over x}} \right)} \right] \times \left[ {\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} {x \over {\sin x}}} \right]  \cr 
  & L = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \left[ {x.\sin \left( {{1 \over x}} \right)} \right] \times 1 \cr} $$ therefore $$L = 0$$    $$x \to 0,\left( {{1 \over x}} \right) \to \infty $$
$$\sin \left( {{1 \over x}} \right) \to 1$$ because $$ - 1 \le \sin \left( {{1 \over x}} \right) \le 1$$